# An Android application with API level 19 does not run on device witn Android 4.4.2

Tags: android

I wrote a [simple Android game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.geographx.LinesGame) with API level 19 (Android 4.4) and OpenGLES 3 in its manifest, but it does not run on some Android phone with Android 4.4.2, Google Play does not allow to download the game showing the message "the application is not supported on your device". [OpenGLES 3 support starts with Android 4.3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). On other Android phones with Android >= 4.4 it runs normally. What can be wrong?

The manifest is provided below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="net.geographx.LinesGame" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="10" android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Application arguments -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="arg1 arg2 arg3"/ -->
            <!-- Application arguments -->

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="LinesGameQt"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so:plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so:lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so:plugins/mediaservice/libqtmedia_android.so:lib/libQt5MultimediaQuick_p.so"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="jar/QtAndroid.jar:jar/QtAndroid-bundled.jar:jar/QtAndroidBearer.jar:jar/QtAndroidBearer-bundled.jar:jar/QtMultimedia.jar:jar/QtMultimedia-bundled.jar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="org.qtproject.qt5.android.multimedia.QtMultimediaUtils:org.qtproject.qt5.android.multimedia.QtMultimediaUtils"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->

            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/ -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/ -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->

            <!-- Background running -->
            <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                          application still try to draw after
                          "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                          signal is sent! -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- Background running -->

            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.auto_screen_scale_factor" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->

            <!-- extract android style -->
            <!-- available android:values :
                * full - useful QWidget & Quick Controls 1 apps
                * minimal - useful for Quick Controls 2 apps, it is much faster than "full"
                * none - useful for apps that don't use any of the above Qt modules
                -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="full"/>
            <!-- extract android style -->
    </activity>

    <!-- For adding service(s) please check: https://wiki.qt.io/AndroidServices -->

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <!-- OpenGL ES 3.0 - This API specification is supported by Android 4.3 (API level 18) and higher.  -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the OpenGL page of the Android dev web site, you can read :

> Caution: Support of the OpenGL ES 3.0 API on a device requires an implementation of this graphics pipeline provided by the device manufacturer. A device running Android 4.3 or higher may not support the OpenGL ES 3.0 API. For information on checking what version of OpenGL ES is supported at run time, see Checking OpenGL ES Version.

That could be the source of your problem...